# Check if a substring is present at a specific location in a string

Tags: python, database, list

I am trying to sort the files in a database based on the filename. The filename consists of characters and numbers e.g- M23GH04.wav. The 2nd and 3rd letter i.e 23 is the class information which i want to use.  Is there a method to pick up all the files having 23 in the 2nd and 3rd position only.

I have tried:

```
spk_id ='23'

spk_files=[f for f in wav_files if spk_id in f]
```

this gives all the files irrespective of the position of '23'. e.g- M01TY23, which is not desirable. Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a list comprehension with slicing:

```
spk_files = [f for f in wav_files if f[1:3] == spk_id]
```

Use the same list comprehension, but just change `spk_id in f` to `f[1:3] == spk_id`, this code makes it only extract the 2nd and the 3rd characters of the filename, then check if it equals to `'23'`, the `spk_id` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `re.match` here:

```
spk_files = [file for file in wav_files if re.match(r'^.23', file)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one .

```
spk_files=[f for f in wav_files if spk_id == f[1:3]]
```

This would match the specific indexes with substring.